# Sit counter or pressure counter?

Tags: sensor, counter, pressure

We have to count how many times a particular chair/seat has been "sat upon" - how would one go about this?

Brute force approach suggests put together a pressure sensor to flip a digital counter.

Is there any elegant approach that can be used in a commercial space inconspicuously?

Comment: Whoo-peee cushion and a noise sensor? Though your pressure sensor and counter sounds easier. Or a micro-switch pulled by a thread through the cushion.

Comment: Large-area capacitance sensor? Suggest using a filter with a long time constant so a hyperactive child doesn't register as hundreds of "sits".

Comment: if it's a hard chair, a temperature sensor driving a counter.

Comment: The auto industry uses these in droves... and they are pretty cheap.. example https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/New-design-car-seat-occupancy-sensor_60634012141.html?spm=a2700.7724857.main07.1.3b80dddcdvPjE1

Comment: So does Ikea on their demonstration rigs

Comment: @SolarMike yes, but there is some assembly required with the Ikea ones ;)

Comment: weight sensor ("scale") beneath the chair? Radar? laser beam interrupter?

Comment: @Trevor_G, yours should be accepted answer.